# How to map a external subfolder to different server (LAN) subfolder in Apache (CentOS Web Panel)

Tags: apache-http-server, rewrite

- **System**: CentOS 6.8 with Centos Web Panel
- **Server**: Apache
- **Server** IP: 10.0.0.150

I have public URL of `sub.domain.com/folder` and I need to Proxy/Rewrite/Map to `10.0.0.253/folder`.

I want `sub.domain.com/folder` show contents of internal server folder. And I don’t want `sub.domain.com` show something, only folder should work. How can I do that?

Most examples assumes that folder in question is on `localhost` server. In my example Apache should act as reverse proxy for communications between WAN clients and LAN server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous answer gave me some hints, but as I am using Centos Web Panel, this answer is directed towards this system.

**Correct for Centos Web Panel**

Recompile Apache in Centos Web Panel, and include these options:

```
--enable-proxy
--enable-proxy-connect
--enable-proxy-ftp
--enable-proxy-http
```

Then, in vhosts configuration (under Apache Settings), add this to vhost:

```
    <VirtualHost>
    ....
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyPass /folder/ http://IP/internal_folder/
       ProxyPassReverse /folder/ http://IP/internal_folder/
    </VirtualHost>
```

Where:

**IP** - IP address or hostname of the server,

**/folder/** - folder you want to "map" (ie: public - domain.com/folder/  , internal server - IP/internal_folder/)

**Note:** don't forget trailing **/** after the folder or hostname.

Answer (score 1):

NOT 100% but you may try this:

try to add the following into  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
    <VirtualHost>
    ....
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyPass /folder http://10.0.0.253/folder
       ProxyPassReverse /folder http://10.0.0.253/folder
    </VirtualHost>
```

restart the server and try accesing `sub.domain.com/folder`

**NOTE:**

you may need to install and activate it

**install:**

```
aptitude install -y libapache2-mod-proxy-html libxml2-dev
```

**activate:**

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_ajp
a2enmod rewrite
a2enmod deflate
a2enmod headers
a2enmod proxy_balancer
a2enmod proxy_connect
a2enmod proxy_html
```

hope it works for you mate.

**EDIT (correct for Centos Web Panel)**

Recompile Apache in Centos Web Panel, and include these options:

```
--enable-proxy
--enable-proxy-connect
--enable-proxy-ftp
--enable-proxy-http
```

Then, in vhosts configuration (under Apache Settings), add this to vhost:

```
    <VirtualHost>
    ....
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyPass /folder/ http://IP/internal_folder/
       ProxyPassReverse /folder/ http://IP/internal_folder/
    </VirtualHost>
```

Where:

**IP** - IP address or hostname of the server,

**/folder/** - folder you want to "map" (ie: public - domain.com/folder/  , internal server - IP/internal_folder/)

**Note:** don't forget trailing **/** after the folder or hostname.

Comment: Thanks mate, you gave me a hint, and it appeared, that I needed to recompile Apache to include these modules. I had to recompile it, because I am using Centos WebPanel.

Comment: @ŽygimantasMarkevičius as long as u got it working mate :)

Comment: Essential was  symbol **/** after the folder. '/folder**/**'

'ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyPass /mm/ http://10.0.0.253/mm/   - main dir
       ProxyPassReverse /mm/ http://10.0.0.253/mm/ 
       ProxyPass /icons/ http://10.0.0.253/icons/ - images
       ProxyPassReverse /icons/ http://10.0.0.253/icons/
       ProxyPass / http://10.0.0.253/mm/ - just in case someone wondered to subdomain.
       ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.0.253/mm/'

Comment: Could I edit your answer to include correct steps? As it is quite specific case covering Centos Web Panel environment.

Comment: @ŽygimantasMarkevičius go for it man, make it useful for everyone. that's the whole point. tyvm

Comment: Should I add it as answer, or it will be to edit your answer?

Comment: @ŽygimantasMarkevičius if my answer is correct but needs slight improvement then edit it please, otherwise answer the question and accept that.